# Icon already includes gloss effects

Tags: ios, ios5, icons

I have a problem with the gloss effect in app icon at iOS 5 beta 5, in iOS 4 it's show the effect not gloss, but iOS5 shows the gloss effect. I put the option `Icon already includes gloss effects = YES`, but simply does not work, and it appears that the application Google+ also has the same problem

Comment: It appears that **facebook** app also have this problem with icon closs. Does anyone have solutions to fix this? Is it a bug iOS5? thanks

Comment: its not any bug, this is default functionality provided by apple.

Comment: @ruiaureliano The link is broken

Answer (score 123):

iOS 5 has anew "Icon Files (iOS 5)" key in the Info.plist file. Make sure the "Icon already includes gloss effect" boolean in that dict is set to "YES" too. You may need to clear your build folder before the changes take effect in the simulator. It takes a lot of troubleshooting to get it to work on older projects, so you might try erasing the root level key.

Comment: worked for me too, but remember if you're deploying backwards to pre iOS5 as well you will still need to include the old boolean too.

Comment: Worked for me too. Accepted answer?

Comment: I knew about the 'Icons' array on the .plist, but never saw "Icon already includes gloss effects", neither "Primary Icon". Does it get this way when you set the deployment target to 5.0?

Answer (score 36):

First Settings in a your project info-list set key **Icon already inculdes gloss effects** to YES Boolean value like below screen shot:

[image]

after try project Target settings tick the **checkbox** in the **summary** tap in the **App Icons** section
like below screen shot:

[image]

it's worked for me!

Welcome in Advance!

Comment: very Thanks @Dinesh It really helped me a lot..!!!+1 for the same.i messed the second approach

Answer (score 22):

It appears this problem is still not fixed in the GM.
I set UIPrerenderedIcon to YES, but the rendered icon includes gloss effect.

---

Sorry, I confirmed that this problem is solved in the GM. If you would like to erase gross effect, set "Icon already includes gross effect" under "Primary Icons" under "Icon files (iOS 5)" to YES.

Answer (score 13):

There are 2 keys in the Info.plist governing this.

xCode generated the following code for you, but it doesn't offer a GUI for changing this:
Open your Info.plist file (Right Click > Open As > Source Code).

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>myIcon.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

set the `UIPrerenderedIcon = true` and you are good to go (this is NOT the other `UIPrerenderedIcon` that also exists in this file as a boolean key!).

Answer (score 11):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this due to a problem using an asset catalog in Xcode 5.0, there is a setting in the Attributes Inspector of the asset catalog that should be checked:

[image: Attributes inspector]

Comment: tried everything else on this thread first, this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks!! That finally did it! Everything else are old solutions.

Comment: My word, what a mess. This is the latest correct answer!

Answer (score 5):

Some of you will do these things and still not have retina display or gloss to reflect these changes.

In XCode 4.3.2 and possibly earlier versions, make sure you check the "Summary" tab in your project settings.  There you will find a section called "App Icons" that should show both your Icon.png and Icon@2x.png. **Make sure you have the "Prerendered Icon" box checked**.

Even after all this, you might not have the retina display working.  **Check the "Info" tab's "Custom iOS Target Properties" section.**

[image: This is where you may find that your plist hasn't updated your Icon files]

Make sure you delete the "Newstand Icons" section if you aren't going to use them or it will stop your app from passing validation when submitting to the AppStore.

Answer (score 3):

In the release notes for iOS5 Beta 6 it says:

> FIXED: The UIPrerenderedIcon key (in the Info.plist file) is not
>   honored in this beta.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's an iOS 5 bug.  I'm sure it'll be fixed in the GM.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with an unwanted gloss effect using xCode 5.0. I went through all posted answers. Here is what worked for me:

1) Remove "Icon Already Includes Gloss Effects" from Info.plist. I did this because, although this is set to "YES", which should work properly -- for whatever reason, it wasn't working, so I wanted to remove it before adding the correct code.

Here's how to do it: 
Click your project name in the navigator (left column) > then in the Editor (middle column) click info. In the field that states "Icon Includes Gloss Effects", click the minus "-" button to delete. This removes the code that is not working, so you will start with a clean palette.

2) Open your Info.plist file -- In the Navigator (left column), find the info.plist file then (Right Click > Open As > Source Code).

3) Your code will look like this:

```
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Icon-120</string>
            <string>Icon-72</string>
            <string>Icon-57</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Now copy the following 2 lines of code, because you will paste them into the code above:

```
     <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <true/>
```

Your final code should look like this:

```
    <dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>YourIconFile</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

This is the best answer I can provide. Worked for me.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I have a universal app and the icon rendered without gloss on the iPhone iOS 6 & 7 and iPad iOS 7. It DID have gloss under iPad iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to change the "Icon already includes gloss effect" boolean under  "Icon Files (iOS 5)" first to NO, compile, then set the boolean to YES and compile.

Answer (score 0):

I set “Icon already includes gloss effects = YES”
In the info.plist, search this part:

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>myIcon.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Now, add this 2 lines:

```
       <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
       <false/>
```

At the end, It must to be:

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>myIcon.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```