# iOS app icon has glossy effect on App store and iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, icons, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an issues with the app Icon on app store, even though I specified in the InfoPlist file the property "Icon already includes gloss effects" to be YES, on iTunes connect and App Store it shows the icon with the glossy effect (on the Home Screen instead it works fine). How can I fix this ?

I read in previous questions here that it was a bug, an it was fixed in September, but my app was published yestarday.. I wrote to Apple support, but I haven't receveid an answer yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it seems was not my problem, in fact without changing anything about the icon, when I submit my updated application on iTunes connect they remove the glossy effect from the app store. But I didn't change any icon settings at all.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 5 includes a new key in your Info.plist for icons, which contains an "Icon already includes gloss effects" entry. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7796604/313875) for more info.

Comment: I have already set it. Do you mean that I have to write it twice ?

Comment: You need it in the new iOS 5 icons entry as well as (if you want to support iOS 4 and below) how it used to be done.

Comment: Yes, there is already set, and in fact it the home screen it works fine.. the problem is with the App store..

Comment: Seeing the gloss effect randomly in itunes for some of my apps as well. I do have the plist entry to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

I am developing an app locally (i.e. haven't yet submitted it to iTunes Connect), but was having the same issue. However, I have found a way to remove gloss from icons on the actual Device (i.e. iPhone) AND the iTunes Apps area. I was helped by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8960594/923817). If you open your InfoPlist file in a text editor, you'll see some lines like:

```
    ...
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>icon@2x.png</string>
                <string>icon.png</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    ...
```

*NOTE: I already changed "UIPrerenderedIcon" in XCode to say "YES", so mine says "true".

To fix the issue, I just copy/pasted the "UIPrerenderedIcon" lines and pasted it above this chunk of code so that it now looks like:

```
    ...
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/> 
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>icon@2x.png</string>
                <string>icon.png</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    ...
```

Seems a little unconventional to have to duplicate code, so there is no telling how long this "fix" will work, but it works for now. for me anyway!

**UPDATE:**

I actually don't think it matters where you paste the

```
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>
```

so long as it is placed outside of the `CFBundleIcons` `<dict>` block on the "main level" with all the other entries.

Comment: on ios4 you can put UIPrerenderedIcon every where you want but on ios5 you must paste in the CFBundlePrimaryIcon key

Answer (score 0):

If you already had set "UIPrerenderedIcon" as True,

Just re-upload your icon with "edit" button. (inside Version Information)