# How to remove the Default Gloss Icon Effect?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have already changed this line :

```
<key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
<true/>
```

I put it correctly in the Info.plist, but it doesn´t work. I have tried a lot to remove this Gloss Effect.

I read all the posts but i couldn´t remove it.

I Have done a little test with an application(App) that doesn´t have this Gloss effect , so i searched for this the UIPrerenderedIcon , the value was true , so i put it in false value , them i respring (and restart) my Iphone , and the Icon appeared still without Gloss Effect , is was suposed to have no gloss effect since i changed the value to false.

I don´t know what´s the problem , i have tried a lot.

I am using Windows.

Program : Plist Editor for Windows
Code : http://pastebin.com/rVp3myj9

What should i do ? I am really upset about it , i have studied a lot to solve this problem , but with no sucess.

I am doing a theme to personalize my iphone , and i am changing the original icons , and some of them had a Gloss Effect , these icons are driving me crazy , because i can´t remove this Gloss Effect.

I would be glad if someone could help me,

Comment: u mean the gloss effect of app icon?

Comment: The parameters are different if you are targeting iOS 5. This will get you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/a/7796604/401092

Comment: Weird, your iPhone runs Windows?

Answer (score 4):

Go to your projects plist file and add and set `Icon already includes gloss effects` check box checked..then run your app and see..

Comment: Ok. Could you show me an example in code ? . I can´t Add row and set it as "yes" because i´m not working on Xcode , i just have a plist to edit in windows. I put it before the </dict> : <key>Icon already includes gloss effects</key>
   <yes/>   . It doesn't work for me , i beg you , please be more specific. Show me an example in plist file as i did above. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

For more reference apart from Mehul answer:

[Remove Shine / Gloss Effect on iPhone Icon](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/general/remove-shine-gloss-effect-on-iphone-icon.html)

Comment: I Saw this link, it doesn't help me. First , as i said above , i am working in windows OS , so i need a modification in plist file , i have tried : <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
<true/>  .It doesn't work for me. I am not working with the XML code because i just have acess to this plist file and i am working in windows System , i don´t have Xcode to acess. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Either check the `Prerendered` checkbox in your project settings next to the App Icons preview boxes, or if you want to do it in code edit the `<YourApp>-Info.plist` to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <!--[...]-->
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <!--[...]-->
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>        


    <!--[...]-->
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>

    <!--[...]-->
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using image sets (Images.xcassets) in XCode 5, then make sure the icon source points to the image set, and in the image set itself you can mark each image as "iOS icon is pre-rendered"

[image]