# Gloss effect for retina and not for low resolution

Tags: xcode, icons

I'm having an issue with the app icon. I've setted the project to omit the gloss efect that adds automatically.

In low res works fine, the icon have not gloss. But in retina display still remaining the gloss effect.

I've made every kind of checks to the used icon and the icon doesn't have gloss added.

Anyone knows what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972650/icon-already-includes-gloss-effects