# icon already includes gloss effects not working ios 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

i am setting my project info-plist file icon already includes gloss effects key to set yes.but,does not work in iOS5 sdk and i am try to build and clean my project folder but,does not work i have tried lot of ways but, doesn't work on ios5 sdk and Xcode 4.2.3.i am setting my project info-list like below screen shot:

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Icon already includes gloss effects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972650/icon-already-includes-gloss-effects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of iOS 5 icon Bugs on the xcode latest version below post my anser will work for me perfectly, i am added prerender checkbox tick project target summary!

follow link must will be help ful!

[Icon already includes gloss effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972650/icon-already-includes-gloss-effects/11272329#11272329)

Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

As you already got your answer, for users of Xcode 4.2 (Snow leopard) Dinesh's solution won't work. Here you can right-click on the info.plist file, and open as source code.

Look for this, and replace `<false/>` with `<true/>`  under `<key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>`

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>iconNormal.png</string>
            <string>iconRetina.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Just drag and drop the icon image in to place, here is the sample screenshot
```

[image]